# Edit woocommerce line total

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to edit the line total of a product in the cart. But for some reason the output is not getting updated. Here is what I have:

```
foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $key => $value ) {
  $value['data']->price = 10;
  $value['line_total'] = 1;
  $value['line_subtotal'] = 1;
}
```

Updating `$value['data']->price`, works fine. But when I try and update `$value['line_total']` or `$value['line_subtotal']`, the output is the same.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Change the `$value['line_total']` or `$value['line_subtotal']`
to `$woocommerce->cart_contents[ $key ]['line_total']` and/or `$woocommerce->cart_contents[ $key ]['line_subtotal']`

You may also want to modify the cart contents total by overriding the value of `$woocommerce->cart_contents_total`

Those variables will just alter the cart total calculations but if you also want to reflect on the cart markup you may want to hook into `'woocommerce_cart_product_subtotal'`

`add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_product_subtotal', 'modify_cart_product_subtotal', 10, 4 );
function modify_cart_product_subtotal( $product_subtotal, $product, $quantity, $cart ) {
    // Add your logic here.
    // You can use the $cart instead of using the global $woocommerce variable.
    return $product_subtotal;
}`

For more detailed reference you can check the `WC_Cart` class documentation here: [Woocommerce Cart](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html)